# MySQL is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch. ruby 2.2.2p95

Tags: mysql, ruby

I'm new to ruby going through a tutorial we are required to create a MySQL database which I have set as an environment variable.

When i installed ruby I selected the option to add Ruby to my environment variables.

Yet I receive an rails errors.

[image]

Comment: You probably need to add `C:\Program Files\....\bin` to `PATH` variable.

Comment: Added MySQL to my Path. Restarted my PC still no luck @dimakura

Comment: Did you also install the rails gem?

Comment: @MarcoSandrini Could you please put your comment as an answer as it has help me fix it

Comment: I think the best way would be if you could write the answer, explaining in details what were the missing steps. Cause I assume that in reality you had to do more than install the rails gem (e.g. install bundler gem, run bundle install, etc...). And then you can accept your own answer .